# How to use tree-sitter parser for syntax highlighting?

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, programming, ide, tree-sitter

I'm trying to setup Emacs for editing Roc (https://www.roc-lang.org/) source code. I have an [LSP server for Roc](https://github.com/ayazhafiz/roc/blob/lang-srv/crates/lang_srv/README.md) and [tree-sitter parser for Roc](https://github.com/faldor20/tree-sitter-roc) installed.

Unfortunately I failed to find tree-sitter documentation for absolute beginners. Initially my configuration was copy-pasted from [this article](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/lets-write-a-treesitter-major-mode) and other examples all over the Internet:

```lisp
;;; Roc

(define-derived-mode roc-mode fundamental-mode "Roc")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.roc\\'" . roc-mode))
;; LSP
(require 'lsp)
(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
  (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration
    '(roc-mode . "roc"))

  (lsp-register-client
    (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection "roc_ls")
                     :activation-fn (lsp-activate-on "roc")
                     :server-id 'theme-check)))
;; tree-sitter
(require 'treesit)
(require 'tree-sitter)
(require 'tree-sitter-langs)

(defun roc-mode-setup ()
  (interactive)
  (treesit-parser-create 'roc)
  (global-tree-sitter-mode)
  (tree-sitter-hl-mode)
  (treesit-major-mode-setup))

(tree-sitter-load 'roc "/home/yshirokov/.emacs.d/tree-sitter/libtree-sitter-roc")
(add-to-list 'tree-sitter-major-mode-language-alist '(roc-mode . roc))
(add-hook 'roc-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (roc-mode-setup)
                           (setq treesit-font-lock-level 4)))
```

Well, with this configuration I have an LSP connection, I can see the types under the cursor in the modeline and can visualize the syntax tree and navigate through it with `treesit-explore-mode`. So, both LSP and tree-sitter parser are probably working. But I have no syntax highlighting.

So I added explicit highlighting rules:

```lisp
;; tree-sitter
(require 'treesit)
(require 'tree-sitter)
(require 'tree-sitter-langs)

(defun roc-mode-setup ()
  (interactive)
  (treesit-parser-create 'roc)
  (setq-local treesit-font-lock-feature-list
              '((comment)
                (keyword)))
  (defvar roc-font-lock-rules
    '(:language roc
      :override t
      :feature comment
      '((comment) @font-lock-comment-face)

      :language roc
      :override t
      :feature keyword
      '((keyword) @font-lock-keyword-face)))

  (global-tree-sitter-mode)
  (tree-sitter-hl-mode)
  (setq-local treesit-font-lock-settings
              (apply #'treesit-font-lock-rules
                     roc-font-lock-rules))
  (treesit-major-mode-setup))
```

But it changed nothing: I still haven't syntax highlighting.

Is it possible to have syntax highlighting for a new language with existing tree-sitter parser? Maybe, there is some step-by-step guide for absolute beginners in tree-sitter mode I missed?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on `fundamental-mode` and then `roc-mode`?

Comment: @MaximKim yes. The effect is the same (no syntax highlighting).

Comment: In regard to "Unfortunately I failed to find tree-sitter documentation for absolute beginners.", the article [How to Get Started with Tree-Sitter](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/how-to-get-started-tree-sitter) seems to be beginner-friendly.

Comment: @Y.E. Thank you. It's a great article, but I already read it (and «Let’s Write a Tree-Sitter Major Mode» in the same blog too, see the link in the question). This article is about _features_ of tree-sitter, but I need the documentation about the _principles_ of tree-sitter modes.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up components of `treesit` (the new build-in tree-sitter package) and `tree-sitter` (the external package for older Emacs versions). If your Emacs has `treesit`, you probably shouldn't be using `tree-sitter`, unless you need to support older versions of Emacs. What happens if you remove the various `tree-sitter` function calls?

Comment: I'm not sure it'll help at all, but I also found [this incomplete guide](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/admin/notes/tree-sitter/starter-guide) attached to the Emacs source (it's an Org file, so it will look better if you open it in Emacs).

Comment: @jirassimok: yes, `treesit` library is enough indeed, thank you. And the guide you found really answered all my questions, now I have working syntax highlighting (see the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. **TL;DR:** yes, explicit highlighting rules are needed; patterns for highlighting rules should match real fragments of syntax tree (in my case Roc syntax tree hasn't `comment` and `keyword` nodes); `tree-sitter` library is not needed in modern Emacs (thank you, [@jirassimok!](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/21490/jirassimok)).

Working config for Roc:

```lisp
;;; Roc

(define-derived-mode roc-mode fundamental-mode "Roc")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.roc\\'" . roc-mode))
;; LSP
(require 'lsp)
(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
  (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration
    '(roc-mode . "roc"))

  (lsp-register-client
    (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection "roc_ls")
                     :activation-fn (lsp-activate-on "roc")
                     :server-id 'theme-check)))
;; tree-sitter
(require 'treesit)

(defun roc-mode-setup ()
  (interactive)
  (defvar roc-font-lock-rules
    (treesit-font-lock-rules
     :language 'roc
     :feature 'string
     '((string) @font-lock-string-face)

     :language 'roc
     :feature 'comment
     '((line_comment) @font-lock-comment-face)

     :language 'roc
     :feature 'definition 
     '((value_declaration_left
        (identifier_pattern
         (long_identifier (identifier) @font-lock-constant-face))))

     :language 'roc
     :feature 'function
     '((application_expression
        caller: 
        (long_identifier_or_op
         (long_identifier (identifier) @font-lock-function-name-face))))))

  (setq-local treesit-font-lock-settings
              roc-font-lock-rules)
  (setq-local treesit-font-lock-feature-list
              '((string comment definition function variable)))
  (treesit-major-mode-setup))

(add-hook 'roc-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (roc-mode-setup)
                           (lsp)
                           (setq treesit-font-lock-level 4)))
```

Problem was solved after reading [this manual](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/admin/notes/tree-sitter/starter-guide), advised by [@jirassimok](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/21490/jirassimok) too. It contains all the missing parts of the puzzle:

- how syntax highlighting with `tree-sitter` works;
- what is a query;
- what is a pattern;
- what is a capture name;
- what is a feature.

I still don't understand how to set the level of the syntax highlighting features, but to be honest I just don't care, it's not an emacs-mode-as-a-software-pet-project.

Source code is already readable enough for me, and anyway I always can add or modify syntax rules, now I know how. Config above contains the rules to highlight string literals, comments, value definitions and function calls:
[image: Syntax highlighting for Roc language in Emacs using tree-sitter]